# ttk.Frame background colour

Tags: python, colors, tk-toolkit, ttk

How can I make the pageframe background colour green? pageframe is frame containing some text. I have tried looking at a lot sites which have stuff about ttk styles but my code still doesn't show the green background even though I have used style.

context= I am creating Diet and exercise management program  for my project but just this green background colour is not working.

I have provided an image how it looks.

I have only included relevant parts of code.

Also I prefer using ttk.Frame() rather than just Frame()

[Diet and exercise management program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HR6v8.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk



root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)#This configures the column and row to be weighted.
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


main = ttk.Frame(root, padding = (3,3,3,3))#This creates the padding around all the contents.
main.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
main.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
main.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)




pagestyle = ttk.Style()
pagestyle.configure("G.TFrame" , background='green')

nav = ttk.Frame(main, borderwidth=2)
nav.grid(column=0, row=0, rowspan = 4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))


pageframe = ttk.Frame(main,style="G.TFrame" )
pageframe.grid(column = 1, row = 0, rowspan =5, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
pageframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


text = Label(pageframe , text="Home")
text.grid(column=0, row=0)

text = Label(pageframe , text="Weekly Overview")
text.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

Comment: That is an awful lot of code I hardly dare to look at but most of it seems to be unrelated to your problem. Probably you can show it with only the root window, the frame and the style.

Comment: ok I will edit the question @Goyo

Comment: Your code raises `NameError: name 'navigation' is not defined`. After removing the offending line I get [a window with a green background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xriu6.png). If it does not work for you it might be a bug specific to your python, tk, operating system...

Comment: oh,  really sorry don't include that. @Goyo

Comment: Do you think it is probably because I am on a MAC?

Comment: It does say as a warning. That (WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.)

Comment: All I know is that your code gives me a green background, if it is different for you it must be due to some differences in our environments. I am using windows 7 32 bits, Python 3.6.3 from python.org and Tcl/Tk 8.6 (included in the python installer).

Comment: The differences are that mine is a MAC and Tcl/Tk version 8.5.9 and yours is windows and  Tcl/Tk version 8.6. I think I just gonna install latest python or use it on windows. Thanks. @Goyo.

Comment: You are aware that the only thing a `ttk.Frame` adds over a standard frame is that it uses the theming system, and usually the only visual signal of that is the background colour, the one thing you are trying to change?